# How to use rollup command in selenium ide?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

> I am new to selenium IDE, As with reference to below image i cant click
>   into rollup icon during and after my recording.

[image: selenium ide rollup]

> So kindly explain me how to, why and what time we should use rollup in
>   selenium IDE.

Comment: This link helped me a little but wanted to know in depth, [link](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-and-where-to-use-rollup-command-in.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys i have ended up with learning of rollup command by the link i mentioned above as it is used to combine the step we often use to test (so by creating an .js we can insert our commands that are been tested often and regular for every test case). [for reference](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-and-where-to-use-rollup-command-in.html)

the below code is what i have done to my .js file and included and it showed me in the selenium IDE.

```
<tr>
<td>rollupAndWait</td>
<td>logincommands</td>
<td></td>
```

> logincommands log in to mail.com
>
> preconditions: postconditions:
>
> current rollup expands to:
>       open | http://gmail.com
>       sendKeys | userName | xxx
>       sendKeys | password | xxx
>       clickAndWait | css=font:btn.contains("xxx")

[image: rollup button]

> so for the rollup button, once you save an rollup.js it is enabled for
>   the tests cases i.e you can press this button to include the rollup in
>   that particular test case.